Property of liftings on $\sigma$-algebra
Given a measure space $(X,\mathcal{E},\mu)$, we say that a lifting on $\mathcal{E}$ is a map $L:\mathcal{E}\rightarrow\mathcal{E}$ such that:

$\mu\left(L(A)\triangle A\right)=0$
If $\mu(A\triangle B)=0$, then $L(A)=L(B)$
$L(X)=X,\ L(\varnothing)=\varnothing$
$L(A\cup B)=L(A)\cup L(B)$
$L(A\cap B)=L(A)\cap L(B)$

Consider the following statement (we can assume that $\mu$ is finite if we need it)

Suppose that $\mathcal{E}=\sigma (\mathcal{A})$ where $\mathcal{A}$ is
an algebra, and that we have $L_1,L_2$ liftings on $\mathcal{E}$ such
that $L_1 |_\mathcal{A}=L_2 |_\mathcal{A}$. Then $L_1=L_2$ on all $\mathcal{E}$.

My question is: is this statement true? I'm trying to prove it using the fact that given $E\in\mathcal{E}$, for every $\varepsilon >0$ there exists $A_\varepsilon\in\mathcal{A}$ such that $\mu(E\triangle A_\varepsilon)<\varepsilon$, but this doesn't seem to help too much.
Related to this question.
